# Determine if light bulbs can be switched on from a given range

Tags: algorithm

Say you have `N` light bulbs that are in a row. You also have `M` switches that in the form `L` to `R`, which can be used to toggle the state of the light bulbs in the range `L` to `R`, both inclusive.

How do I determine if there exists way to switch on all the light bulbs, by using any of these `M` switches, any number of times? (I just want to know whether it is possible or not)

One straightforward way is to try all possible combinations of the switches and check if the light bulbs are all turned on. But this is extremely inefficient. Is there a better way to do the same?

The number of light bulbs and switches are limited to `1000`.

Example:

If there are `10` light bulbs and `3` switches that toggle the bulbs in the range `1` to `7`, `6` to `7`, `6` to `10`, then we can use all of the switches exactly once, and turn all the light bulbs from `1` to `10` on.

Comment: How many light bulbs or switches can be there?

Comment: @merlyn, there can be 1000 light bulbs and switches. Updated the question.

Comment: Gaussian elimination can solve this in O(n^3) which should finish in a couple seconds. But the clumped values of switches might allow a better algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

merlyn's right. If you implement LU decomposition with partial pivoting, then by careful pivot selection you can ensure that the reduced rows are always intervals. The really striking part is that, on further analysis, we don't even need to do the decomposition. It actually suffices to determine whether there is a path between `1` and `N+1` in a graph where each switch `L..R` gives rise to an edge `{L, R+1}`.

Comment: I see. I don't really know about the Gaussian elimination, I have to learn that.  Thank you.